# Removing repeated pairs from a very big text file

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have a very big text file (few GB) that has the following format:

```
1 2
3 4
3 5
3 6
3 7
3 8
3 9
```

File is already sorted and double lines  were removed. There are repeated pairs like '2 1', '4 3' reverse  order that I want to remove. Does anybody have any solution to do it in a very resource limited environments, in BASH, AWK, perl or any similar languages?  I can not load the whole file and loop between the values.

Comment: I don't get it: you got repeated pairs and you already removed the duplicate ... how is that possible ?! Can you explain ?

Comment: @ouki he means that he has like 1, 2 and then later 2, 1

Comment: Are you able to re-sort the list if necessary? If so, I have a solution

Comment: Can't you reverse order if 1st number > 2nd number before sorting and removing dups in the file the first time?

Comment: @user1297220, Is it possible to get `4 2` without `2 4`? If so, what should be output?

Comment: @Alan, Yes it is possible  to re sort the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution:

- Scan the file
- For any pair where the second value is less than the first, swap the two numbers
- Sort the pairs again by first then second number
- Remove duplicates

I'm still thinking about more efficient solution in terms of disk sweeps, but this is a basic naive approach

Comment: "I can not load the whole file and loop between the values." --OP

Comment: @ninjagecko he would not need to, he would only need to scan one line at a time, it sounds like he was already able to sort and remove duplicates. I believe he meant he can't store the whole file in memory to make checking for duplicates easier

Comment: But how would he sort the file without reading the whole thing into memory?

Answer (score 4):

You want to remove lines where the second number is less than the first?

```
perl -i~ -lane'print if $F[0] < $F[1]' file
```

Comment: It might be the case that he considers `1 2` to be equivalent to `2 1`, and IF `1 2` appears, then `2 1` should not also appear. At least that's how I'm reading the question. Perhaps OP could clarify.

Comment: No there are many pairs like <122 , 1444> and <1444 , 122>, I want to remove <1444 , 122> and just have <122 , 1444>

Comment: That's what my code does. The problem is that you haven't specified what should happen when you have 1444,122 without 122,1444. You haven't specified anything new. Please clarify.

Comment: @ikegami wouldn't your code take a file with the single value {4,1} and output nothing?

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. This was not what I was looking for, but it is working and solved my problem.

Comment: My pairs are symmetric, As Alan, mentioned, it would not work it the pairs are not symmetric.

Comment: @platoali If this solves your problem, please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

For each value, perform a binary search on the file on the hard drive, without loading it into memory. Delete the duplicate if you see it. Then do a final pass that removes all instances of two or more `\n`.

Comment: How to do that? Would you please be more specific?

Comment: that's a not a bad idea, assuming your pairs are in order.

So if you have {1,2} you can flip it {2, 1} do a search for this value, using a binary search, if you find it delete it. But this involves a lot of disk seeking..

Comment: @Alan: if the OP does not have the memory to load the file into memory, I do not see a solution that does not involve lots of disk reads and writes.

Comment: @ninjagecko I agree, and I think it is possible you have the best approach

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure if this works / if it's any good...

```
awk '{ if ($2 > $1) print; else print $2, $1 }' hugetext | sort -nu -O hugetext
```

Comment: Considering the highest scoring answer, you could suffice with `awk '$1<$2 { print }' hugetext`

Comment: @Bernhard, I know what you mean. But then the OP said, "...it would not work it the pairs are not symmetric". There's no guarantee it'll always be symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

You want remove duplicates considering `1 2` and `2 1` to be the same?

```
< file.in \
| perl -lane'print "@F[ $F[0] < $F[1] ? (0,1,0,1) : (1,0,0,1) ]"' \
| sort -n \
| perl -lane'$t="@F[0,1]"; print "@F[2,3]" if $t ne $p; $p=$t;' \
> file.out
```

This can handle arbitrarily large files.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane '
    END{
        print for sort {$a<=>$b} keys %h;
    }

    $key = $F[0] < $F[1] ? "$F[0] $F[1]" : "$F[1] $F[0]";
    $h{$key} = "";
' file.txt
```

**Explanations** :

1. I sort the current line in numeric order
2. I make the hash key variable `$key` by concatenating first and second value with a space
3. I defined the `$hash{$key}` to nothing
4. At the end, I print all the keys sorted in numeric order.

A hash key is uniq by nature, so no duplicate.

You just need to use `Unix` redirections to create a new file.

Comment: This will produce a very very big hash in memory. when the memory is exhausted, the process will be killed. I can not load the whole data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general O(n) algorithm to do this in 1 pass (no loops or sorting required):

1. Start with an empty hashset as your blacklist (a set is a map with just keys)
2. Read file one line at a time.
3. For each line:

   - Check to see this pair is in your blacklist already.
   - If so, ignore it.
   - If not, append it to your result file; and also add the swapped value to the blacklist (e.g., if you just read "3 4", and "4 3" to the blacklist)

This takes O(n) time to run, and O(n) storage for the blacklist. (No additional storage for the result if you manipulate the file as r/w to remove lines as you check them against the blacklist)

Comment: And how much memory would that require? ;-)

Comment: Would you would have to store your black list in memory for this to be better than just using an N^2 looping structure over the disk?

Comment: To decrease memory usage one could only store the $smaller,$greater  pair and then covert all the pairs to the $smaller,$greater format before comparing.